# Hibernate - huge parameter list - slow query

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have a "simple" query with few inner joins and WHERE clause with "IN" which has 30,000-50,0000 ids inside. I use Java with Hibernate (JPA, QueryDSL).
I used JProfiler and debugged it myself after it, and what I found out is:

1. query executes in less then 1 second
2. hibernate parsing lasts longer than 2 minutes (hibernate's getHQLQueryPlan method)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can improve the performance of hibernate. Take a look at [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html). This might help you out.

Comment: try to devide your dsl query into more than one query also try to use bach-size property on your models

Comment: One solution would be to create a temporary table, insert the ids in the table and join on this table.

Comment: yep, I did it that way, thanks Priyesh :)